# Meaning of 'reducing the odds'

Tags: meaning

Could someone please explain me the meaning of the phrase 'reducing the odds'.
I actually saw this phrase in a game show.....Here is the sentence:
'He came up with a perfect strategy in order to reduce the odds'.Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

[**Odds**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odds) is synonymous with "chances" or "possibilities", but it is more broadly used when talking about a negative result than a positive one.

> the probability that one thing is so or will happen rather than
>   another

[Merriam-Webster]

Your example sentence could be rephrased to:

> He came up with a perfect strategy in order to reduce the chances of *losing* or *being defeated* in the game.

Comment: Not explicitly spelled out in your answer: reducing the odds means to make something less likely to occur.